# download list from a website

Tags: pdf, download, website

Let's say there is a website with a list of all companies from a specific branch in USA. This large data (let's say 10000 records) is displayed with 100 records per site (if you want more you can click on next site, and so on.)

I would like to know an easy and fast way to download all this data to a pdf.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you give us a link to the site? Also, what's your operating system? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Acrobat does that. Give it a URL, tell it to stay on the same server. There is a free trial if you don't want to spend the money, or if you just need to do it once. You can see a tutorial on how to do that here: http://www.ghacks.net/2008/04/12/convert-a-full-website-into-pdf/

Comment: That only works for one site though, not for thousands of records over a few hundred sites where you have to click "next site".

Comment: For easy methods, doubtful. You would have to write a program to do it otherwise.